# JavaMailMessage.GetContent returning IMAPInputStream occasionally

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, imap, spring-integration

Im trying to read emails from lotus notes using spring integrations email pollers  ,using IMAP.

All seems to work well .

the getcontect method of javamailMessage received is an instanceOf String or Multipart as expected. i have this handled in my code.

Sometimes getcontent returns an Inputstream. It happens occasionally . Once we restart the jvm ,it seems to work fine for a period and then it starts to happen again . Any idea/suggesstions as to why this can happen.
I did read the javadoc

" For content types that are unknown to the DataHandler system, an input stream is returned as the content."

when does javamailmessage.getcontent() can be an instanceOf Inputstream . how can i find out content types that are unknown to the DataHandler system

My application is built using gradle . I use javamail 1.4.7 .

```
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version:'1.4.7'
compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'mailapi', version:'1.4.7'
compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'imap', version:'1.4.7'
```

I use spring 3.1.3 and spring Integration 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail 1.4.7 is pretty old, you should [upgrade to 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) if possible.

See the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) to understand how to handle many different content types.

You can use the getContentType method to see the content type that isn't being handled by your program.

Comment: The reason I settled with 1.4.7 was because 1.5.2 did not work well with the spring versions that we use . I will try and upgrade the version . To my original question - do you know when the getcontentype can return an inputstream. Is it something to do with a mailcap file not being loaded or found

Comment: Yes, it depends on the mailcap file to find the right class to handle each data type, but if you're correctly getting Multipart objects that means it must be finding the default mailcap file.  There's a huge number of possible MIME types that have no default mapping to Java.  What you need to figure out is whether you're running into one of those MIME types or whether you're getting a common MIME type that should have a mapping but the mapping is broken.  For example, a common attachment MIME type is application/pdf, but there's no default mapping for that MIME type.

Comment: For the same mimetype multipart/mixed (if I remember correct ) I get multipart most of the times . Sometimes i get inputstream

Comment: Something is clearly broken.  JavaMail uses JAF to handle the MIME type to Java mapping.  JAF uses the ClassLoader to find the mailcap file that configures the mapping.  If the ClassLoader is broken, it might not be able to find the mapping sometimes.  What application server are you running in?  What JDK version are you using?

Comment: Vfabric tc server , Jdk 1.7 .

Comment: Is JavaMail installed in tomcat's lib directory?  Or is it bundled with your application?

Comment: It seems to Be working as expected for a period of time . Then all of a sudden some emails read come in as inputstream . Could it because of a class loader hierarchy change at run time

Comment: Yes, if you're changing the class loader hierarchy at runtime, that could break it.  JAF depends on the thread's context class loader being set properly to be able to find the mailcap file that's bundled in the JavaMail jar file.  If the JavaMail jar file isn't in tomcat's lib directory, try putting it there.

Comment: I did try putting it there a couple of days back  . It did not help . And yes it is bundled with the app

Comment: Try taking it out of the app.

Comment: I upgrade javamail to 1.5.2 and JAF to 1.1.1 as suggested in the Readme of javamail.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.set(ParameterList.java:540)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.parseParameters(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:404)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:224)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE.<init>(BODYSTRUCTURE.java:109)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parseItem(FetchResponse.java:198)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parse(FetchResponse.java:164)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:92)
  ...

Comment: ok i included     compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'mailapi', version:'1.5.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'imap', version:'1.5.2' and it seems to have fixed the issue .

Comment: You have a mix of old and new JavaMail classes on your class path. Which jar files are on your class path?

Comment: Updated everything to 1.5.2 and they are working : I did not have the mailapi jars updated to 1.5.2. I had another dependency that had 1.4.7 for these jars in it . It is working now . I am just hoping this update will resolve the original inputstream issue from the getcontent method

Comment: It probably won't. Did you try taking JavaMail out of the app?

Comment: Yeah I did . It did not help . The issue occurred with that setup also.

Comment: But then I did it with jaf 1.1 and not jaf 1.1.1

Comment: With JDK 1.7, you don't need JAF at all since it's built in to JDK 1.7.  Are you changing the class loader hierarchy at runtime?

Comment: No I am not changing class loader hierarchy myself . I am no sure if any of the spring integrations jars are doing it . Jdk 1.7 had jaf 1.1 . I could not get jaf 1.1.1 without explicitly declaring a dependency in my gradle build

Comment: When you get an InputStream instead of the String you suspect, create an Exception object and ask it to print out the stack trace.  That might provide a clue as to what path your app is going through that causes the problem to occur.

Comment: I have that in place . I will get back to you when I have more information . Thanks very much for your responses

Comment: I updated it to 1.5.2 .I did not get any issues until yesterdat . Today the issue started occuring again

Comment: Sent the same email with same attachments twice

Comment: printed     mailMessage.getContentType();
         printed   mailMessage.getDisposition();
   Enumeration<URL> resources =           getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/mailcap");
   while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
    logger.debug(resources.nextElement());
   }
                         Object content = mailMessage.getContent();
   logger.debug("Mail message content: " + content);

Comment: First email : Mail message content type: multipart/mixed;                
       Mail message content disposition: inline
       jar:file:/.../webapps/EmailService/WEB-INF/lib/mailapi-1.5.2.jar!/META-INF/mailcap
       Mail message content: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@1b6b53c3

Comment: Second email : 

  Mail message content type: multipart/mixed;   
  Mail message content disposition: inline
  jar:file:/.../webapps/EmailService/WEB-INF/lib/mailapi-1.5.2.jar!/META-INF/mailcap
  Mail message content: javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream@18ff918d

Comment: sorry about the formatting in the above three messages . not sure what happened with it .

Comment: Did you get a stack trace when this happens?

Comment: I did not get an exception thrown. from  mail.message . I threw my own exception when I got an inputStream instead of multipart .  It just has some spring related stack trace.

Comment: One thing I noticed is there are other wars deployed in same tc server instance . And they have java mail 1.4.7 which are class loaded when required . But I thought resources loaded by one context class loader are not visible to others in tomcat in general . Would that be a problem in anyway .  Also had this module brining in an SMTP provider jar 1.4.7 . I updated that and restarted the jvm and the issue is not occurring anymore . I wondering if any of these were related

Comment: If each app has exactly one JavaMail jar file, and there is none in Tomcat's directories, that should work.  If it still fails after your latest changes, please tell me exactly which JavaMail jar files are exactly where in the server, including in exactly which war files, and show me the exact stack trace when it fails.

Comment: By fail - do you mean Javan.mail.message.getcontent() returning a sharedbytearrayInputstream. Is there a way to attach a file here

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  If you'd like to take this debugging offline, contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: Sure thanks . I will send you the information there from my gmail or iCloud account